# Why this file can't be deleted?

Tags: java, file-io, junit, guava

I wrote unit test (JUnit 4) that performs some logic and writes result to file. In `@Before` annotated method it creates file and in `@After` the file should be deleted. It isn't though, and I can't figure it out, why.

I am using Google Guava 10.01 Files API. Here's my unit test code:

```
public class CashierTest extends ContextedTest {

    private File cashierFile;

    @Before
    public void createFile() throws Exception {
        cashierFile = new File("D://workspace-sts/spring-miso/cashier.txt");
        cashierFile.createNewFile();
    }

    @After
    public void release() {
        if (cashierFile.exists()) {
            if (!cashierFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't delete cashier file");
            }
        }
        cashierFile = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testCashier() throws Exception {
        // file shouldn't contain any text
        assertFalse(Files.toString(cashierFile, Charset.defaultCharset()).length() > 0);

        Cashier cashier = (Cashier) context.getBean("cashier");
        ShoppingCart cart = (ShoppingCart) context.getBean("shoppingCartPrototype");
        cashier.checkout(cart);

        assertTrue(cashierFile.exists());
        // file should contain text now
        assertTrue(Files.toString(cashierFile, Charset.defaultCharset()).length() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setPath() {
        path = "sk/xorty/advancedioc/beans.xml";
    }
}
```

Note: `ContextedTest` superclass is my test which holds Spring container it isn't relevant atm.

Comment: Could it be, that the file has been opened by one of the tests but not properly closed, i.e., there is still some open stream lying around, which references the file?

Comment: @Dirk: No, I don't think so, this is the only test that uses that file.

Comment: @Dirk: Actually yes, Cashier had opened stream :) Write down answer and I shall accept it.

Comment: what about that `cashier` thing used by the test. Does that object open the file (and keeping it open)? The object is likely to be still lying around in memory by the time, the `@After` method is called.

Comment: Correct, I fixed that inside cashier.

Comment: `assertFalse (Files.toString(cashierFile, Charset.defaultCharset()).length() > 0);` or `assertFalse(cashierFile.length() > 0);` or just `assertTrue(!cashierFile.exists() && cashierFile.delete());`

Comment: Yep, good idea just asking for byte length of file itself, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply instanting a `File` does **not** mean that an actual file will be created. Call `createNewFile()` or `createTempFile()` on that instance for this.

Within your test method you don't seem to pass that file reference to anyone that could possibly create the file or write anything in it... Am I missing something or is the code you posted missing some key lines ?

Comment: I added createNewFile call to @After annotated method, but the file still won't be deleted though.

Comment: Yes I the file itself isn't passed but Cashier instance opened file with same path as in test. Sorry I didn't notice, you couldn't have known this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [TemporaryFolder](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) Rule with JUnit 4. This will handle the setup and teardown of temporary test directories and files.

```
public static class HasTempFolder {
  @Rule public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
    File createdFile= folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
    ...
  } 
}
```

[Other Rules](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/package-summary.html) are part also part of Junit 4.